# Kubernetes PODs : Spring Boot Application with java file handling. How to create multiple pods and share the files across pods

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

We are recently exploring kubernetes and pods based deployments. We have one Spring Boot Project which performs various Java File Operations (Read/Write), like create excel, create pdf, create text files. And through our Java application we can download these files from UI at any point of time. ***We are using "java.nio.file.Files" to save/store the files and "org.springframework.core.io.Resource" to load the files.***

My question is: If we create multiple pods, then ***how these files (Excel/PDF/Text/Etc) can be shared by other pods so that horizontal scaling via pod work seamlessly.***

Comment: Assuming your environment supports it, you could allocate a [ReadWriteMany](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) [persistent volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) and share that between your pods. Alternatively, you could rewrite your code to store files in an object storage system like AWS S3.

Comment: Hi Thanks for response. Since I am new to Kubernetes, May you please provide some directions on how may I implement ReadWriteMany and Persistent Volume. I tried implementing persistent volume, but even though once Pod is deleted, my file data is also deleted.